# Is there a simple example of false-positive valgrind "possibly lost" report?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

From reading about the valgrind memory leak report of "possibly lost", I had understood that there is a very small chance that this kind of report will be a false-positive report. What I could not understand how this can occur on a normal circumstances without doing something very forced to the code.

So for understanding this option, I am asking is there a simple example of false-positive valgrind "possibly lost" memory leak report?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a false positive of "possibly lost":

```
class A {
    int x;
};
class B {
    int y;
};
class C : public A, B {
    int z;
};

int main() {
    static B* notLost = new C();    //The upcast will change the pointer to point 4 bytes into the object, because that is the offset of the B subobject within the C object.
    //Valgrind thinks, the new object may be possibly unreachable.
    //But I can still do this:
//  delete (C*)notLost; //The downcast undoes the pointer modification by the upcast.
}
```

Here is a more generic example of a false positive:

```
//get asprintf
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

char* getFoo() {
    static char* foo = NULL;
    if(!foo && asprintf(&foo, "Hello World\n") < 0) assert(0);
    return foo;
}

int main() {
    printf("%s", getFoo());
}
```

This is a typical singleton ideom: There is a function somewhere, that provides access to a special object (here the "Hello World" string), ensuring that there is only one such object ever created. Since the object is never destructed/deallocated, Valgrind has to think that it is a memory leak. Usually these are listed as "still reachable", since there is still the static variable through which it can be accessed, but it is a false positive nevertheless.

Comment: Is there also an good example for the case of "possibly lost" report, because I did not understand how there could be a false-positive report in that case?

Comment: @user2579277: Sorry, I could not respond sooner, I have now added a more direct example.

Comment: I am sorry but your new example for possibly lost does not show as problem in an valgrind report. And for the second example, asprint allocate memory in it's core so the valgrind report is not false positive.

Comment: @user2579277: I've just verified the "possibly lost" example, you get the false positive if you comment out the delete statement, maybe I was not clear enough on that. The other example is indeed slightly wrong in that it turns up as "still reachable" instead of "lost", but that's the classic false positive with valgrind. I do not think it's possible to construct a sensible false positive for "lost", though.

Comment: This second answer is wrong. The example code shows a 'still reachable', not a 'possibly lost'. An example in C would be code using something like Pascal laypout strings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432262/data-layout-for-pascal-string-in-c and stroring the pointer to the start of the string.